# Stumped, retrieving a string from class

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a custom table cell class.

TextInput.h

```
@interface TextInput : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UILabel *cellLabel;
    UITextField *textFieldBox;
    NSString *imageFile;  
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textFieldBox;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *cellLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageFile;
```

It has a camera button in it and saves the image to the local documents folder. I save the file name to imageFile, which is generated with a unique name.

Textinput.m

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    //retrieve image
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: @"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    imageFile = [self findUniqueSavePath];

    [self saveImage:image:imageFile];
    //dismiss the camera 
     CoreTableAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (CoreTableAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainDelegate.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
}

- (NSString *)findUniqueSavePath {
    NSString *path;
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    NSString *uuidString = [(NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid) autorelease];
    CFRelease(uuid);
    path = [uuidString stringByAppendingPathExtension: @"png"];
    return path;
}
```

Everything works fine except when I want to retrieve the name of the file from the parent UItableView class.

EditTankDescription.m

```
- (void)getCell
{

    TextInput *cell1 = (TextInput *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];    
    NSLog(@"save imageFile:%@", cell1.imageFile); <***** crashes on this line

}
```

It crashes on the NSLog statement with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It's like imageFile is not a NNString. If I set imageFile = @"SOme random string" , there is no error.
I'm stumped.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
imageFile = [self findUniqueSavePath];
```

You're not retaining the `imageFile` ivar.  By the time you go to read the string it is a dangling pointer and you get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Instead, use the property accessor, which will handle the release and retain for you:

```
self.imageFile = [self findUniqueSavePath];
```

Alternatively you can set the ivar directly, in which case you need to do the memory management yourself:

```
[imageFile release];
imageFile = [[self findUniqueSavePath] retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the first line of getCell. It is likely that cell1 is nil. 
Is your index path correct? Perhaps there is only one row in section zero? Rows are also zero-indexed:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
```

Comment: Good thought but cell1 does return a TextInput uitableview cell. If I retrieve a random string, it's fine. It crashes only with imageFile.

Comment: I think I've come to the conclusion that there's something strange about a UITableViewCell class. It doesn't like non view type properties. So if I store my file name into a UIlable and retrieve it like NSString myFile = cell1.cellLable.text, it works out fine.